# Display a 1 GB video file in react js frontend, stored in private S3 bucket using flask

Tags: reactjs, flask, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to display/stream large video files in reactjs. These files are being uploaded to private s3 bucket by user using react form and flask.

I tried `getObject` method, but my file size is too large. `get a signed url` method required me to download the file.

I am new to AWS-python-react setup. What is the best/most efficient/least costly approach to display large video files in react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS offers other streaming specific services but if you really want to get them off S3 you could retrieve the files using torrent which, with the right client/videoplayer would allow you to start playing them without having to download the whole file.

Since you mentioned you're using Python, you could do this using AWS SDK like so:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = client.get_object_torrent(
    Bucket='my_bucket',
    Key='/some_prefix/my_video.mp4'
)
```

The response object will have this format:

```py
{
    'Body': StreamingBody()
}
```

Full docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object_torrent).

Then you could use something like [webtorrent](https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent) to stream it on the frontend.

Two things to note about this approach (quoting [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3Torrent.html)):

> - Amazon S3 does not support the BitTorrent protocol in AWS Regions launched after May 30, 2016.
> - You can only get a torrent file for objects that are less than 5 GBs in size.

Comment: hey thanks. I was earlier using firebase. Someone suggested me to use s3 (coz s3 is cheaper than firebase). I am open to exploring other storage options as well.

Comment: Np. S3 as an object storage solution was actually a good and cost effective suggestion but by itself, it's not the best option for your use case. Not sure about the scope of your project but you should definitely look into CloudFront, which is a CDN service that, among other things, allows you to set up [RTMP (streaming) distributions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-overview-rtmp.html) with S3 as origin. Meaning you can store the files on S3 and take advantage of its storage capabilities while also leverage the benefits of a CDN & streaming.

Comment: Thanks, will check this out. Also, if further context could help -- assume that each user can upload video files occupying upto 30GB (per month). And all these videos are to be displayed in reactjs. Assume I can have upto 1000 users per month.

Comment: Even with the new info I still stand by my previous answer/comments.

Comment: Hi, the video file is not loading in reactjs https://codepen.io/drngke/pen/abNGbEg

Comment: Look at the errors in the console, you have several errors `[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://YOUR_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/s3outputx.mp4.torrent due to access control checks.`, `Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful` and `Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-downloads', 'allow-presentation' are invalid sandbox flags.`, some suggest you're having issues with [CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) and others that probably CodePen doesn't allow downloads. Other thing, WebTorrent requires a `magnetURI` not a torrent file.

Comment: Torrent file is acceptable. This is a text file that is being loaded in codepen https://codepen.io/drngke/pen/zYqjYPX