# Get webTorrent to play .mp4 file stored in AWS private s3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, video, video-streaming, webtorrent

I am using reactjs and flask. After getting the torrent of .mp4 file stored in private s3 bucket, I am trying to displayand play it in browser using webtorrent.
But the video content is not loading

This is a follow up question to [Load and play 1 GB .mp4 in reactjs, stored in private s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63747857/display-a-1-gb-video-file-in-react-js-frontend-stored-in-private-s3-bucket-usin/63748412?noredirect=1#comment112776141_63748412). For now, the s3 bucket is public. Because private file was throwing error.

Code for reference - https://codepen.io/drngke/pen/abNGbEg

```
const magnet = 'https://datavocal.s3.amazonaws.com/s3outputx.mp4.torrent'

const client = new WebTorrent()

client.add(magnet, (torrent) => {
  console.log(torrent.files)
  
   torrent.files[0].appendTo('body')

});
client.on("error", (err) => console.log(err))
```

Comment: I saw your original post and never answered (sorry).  I've answered this one with what I could figure out... Unfortunately I don't think this is possible, though I'd welcome a second analysis incase I've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work.

From the [webtorrent](https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent) docs:

> To make BitTorrent work over WebRTC (which is the only P2P transport that works on the web) we made some protocol changes. Therefore, a **browser-based WebTorrent client or "web peer" can only connect to other clients that support WebTorrent/WebRTC**.

And further:

> **To seed files to web peers, use a client that supports WebTorrent**, e.g. WebTorrent Desktop, a desktop client with a familiar UI that can connect to web peers, webtorrent-hybrid, a command line program, or Instant.io, a website.

So I'm guessing S3 would have to support WebTorrent/WebRTC which I don't think it will.

> [image]

If my understanding of the above diagram is correct, you could run a hybrid client in between S3 and your web-peers, however you'd then need to host the hybrid somewhere which kind of makes S3 redundant in that setup.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I got a similar answer on WebTorrent github as well. That I need to start my own hybrid peer in a private server. AWS doesnt have browser peers (aka WebRTC peers) seeding the file. I am now trying to send this file from flask to react using `send_file` and failing. In case you know how to send, and stream mp4 video in reactjs that would be very helpful.

Comment: **(1)** Why not leave out the complicated torrent stuff and just keep an **actual** MP4 file online somewhere (eg: DropBox or Github or your own website folder). **(2)** Test a different [MP4 like this one](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4), does it play when used as a torrent on your S3 server? This test will confirm if your own file is the problem causing none playback.

Comment: @VC.One **(2)** Tried that mp4. still getting the same result in browser. Codepen for reference - https://codepen.io/drngke/pen/abNGbEg. 
For **(1)** User is uploading the data, so cant really store it in dropbox, right? I am not very keen on torrent now. Trying to download the file in backend (flask) and then send it over to frontend (react). If you have ideas on how to do it, do share.

Comment: Figured. I just needed to pass the endpoint that returns the actual path of the file. So, for @app.route('/vid/<filename>') which returns send_file('path_of_video'), pass <video src='/vid/output.mp4'>